# Failed to pass assetManager from java to c++ by using JNI

Tags: android, c++, java-native-interface

I'd like to using some asset files of my app in native c++ code, so I have some testing code like follows:

**Java**

```
package com.example.andy.textureviewtest;
import ...

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AssetManager assetManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sample_text);
        tv.setText(stringFromJNI());
        assetManager = getAssets();
        generateAssets(assetManager);
    }

    public native String stringFromJNI();

    public native int generateAssets(AssetManager assetManager);

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("native-lib");
    }
}
```

**C++**

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <string>
#include <android/asset_manager.h>
#include <android/asset_manager_jni.h>
#include <android/log.h>

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_example_andy_textureviewtest_MainActivity_stringFromJNI(
    JNIEnv* env,
    jobject /* this */) {
  std::string hello = "Hello from C++";
  return env->NewStringUTF(hello.c_str());
}

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_example_andy_textureviewtest_MainActivity_generateAssets(
    JNIEnv* env,jobject thiz,jobject assetManager) {
  AAssetManager* mgr = AAssetManager_fromJava(env, assetManager);
  AAssetDir* assetDir = AAssetManager_openDir(mgr, "");
  const char* filename = (const char*)NULL;
  while ((filename = AAssetDir_getNextFileName(assetDir)) != NULL) {
    AAsset* asset = AAssetManager_open(mgr, filename, AASSET_MODE_UNKNOWN);
    off_t bufferSize = AAsset_getLength(asset);
}
  return 0;
}
```

but when my app runs, I only got this error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for int com.example.andy.textureviewtest.MainActivity.generateAssets(android.content.res.AssetManager) (tried Java_com_example_andy_textureviewtest_MainActivity_generateAssets and Java_com_example_andy_textureviewtest_MainActivity_generateAssets__Landroid_content_res_AssetManager_2)
```

Anything wrong here that I might have missed?

Answer (score 1):

Your C++ functions probably are missing

```
extern "C"
```

prefix. Their exported names are mangled by the C++ compiler, and JNI fails to resolve them.

Comment: Which is why there's a `javah` command to generate proper header files.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: including header files is not necessary for JNI, but it definitely makes the life easier.

Comment: adding extern "C" before two native functions still get same error@AlexCohn

Comment: OK, let's debug the situation. In your NDK, find the file `arm-linux-androideabi-nm` and run it with parameters `-D libnative-lib.so`. You will see the actual name of the `Java_com_example_andy_textureviewtest_MainActivity_generateAssets` function; it could happen that this name is mangled, or hidden.

Comment: After run arm-linux-androideabi-nm,I got something like this, _Z65Java_com_example_andy_textureviewtest_MainActivity_generateAssetsP7_JNIEnvP8_jobjectS2_

Comment: ... which means that you did not apply `extern "C"` correctly

Comment: Oh, that's exactly where the question is, I forgot to use {} with extern "C".Thanks a lot for the answer!