# No implementation found for int com.example.nimashahbazi.mooshak.EncryptingActivity.encrypt

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I am trying to use a C++ code in an android app but I keep getting this error (no need to mention this is my first time using NDK):

```
com.example.nimashahbazi.mooshak E/art: No implementation found for int com.example.nimashahbazi.mooshak.EncryptingActivity.encrypt(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String) (tried Java_com_example_nimashahbazi_mooshak_EncryptingActivity_encrypt and Java_com_example_nimashahbazi_mooshak_EncryptingActivity_encrypt__Ljava_lang_String_2Ljava_lang_String_2Ljava_lang_String_2)
com.example.nimashahbazi.mooshak D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
com.example.nimashahbazi.mooshak E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.nimashahbazi.mooshak, PID: 17797
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for int com.example.nimashahbazi.mooshak.EncryptingActivity.encrypt(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String) (tried Java_com_example_nimashahbazi_mooshak_EncryptingActivity_encrypt and Java_com_example_nimashahbazi_mooshak_EncryptingActivity_encrypt__Ljava_lang_String_2Ljava_lang_String_2Ljava_lang_String_2)
at com.example.nimashahbazi.mooshak.EncryptingActivity.encrypt(Native Method)
at com.example.nimashahbazi.mooshak.EncryptingActivity.onCreate(EncryptingActivity.java:35)
...
```

This is my EncryprtingActivity.java:

```
package com.example.nimashahbazi.mooshak;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class EncryptingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

static {

    try
    {
        System.loadLibrary("native-lib");
        System.loadLibrary("aes256");


    }
    catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError use)
    {
        Log.e("JNI", "WARNING: Could not load native library");
    }

}
public native int encrypt(String encryptionKey, String inputFile, String outputFile);


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_encrypting);

    String input= Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory("Android/data/"+ getApplicationContext().getPackageName()+"/Files/Download").toString()+"DSC_0001.jpg";
    String output= Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory("Android/data/"+ getApplicationContext().getPackageName()+"/Files/Download").toString()+"DSC_0001.jpg.encr";

    encrypt("12345678",input,output);
}

public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent mainIntent = new Intent(EncryptingActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
    EncryptingActivity.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
    EncryptingActivity.this.finish();
}
}
```

and this is my native-lib.cpp:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string>
#include "aes256.cpp"

using namespace std;

#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024*1024

JNIEXPORT jint  JNICALL
Java_com_example_nimashahbazi_mooshak_EncryptingActivity_encrypt(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj,
                                                                 jstring encryptionKey,
                                                                 jstring inputFile,
                                                                 jstring outputFile);

JNIEXPORT jint  JNICALL
Java_com_example_nimashahbazi_mooshak_DecryptingActivity_decrypt(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj,
                                                                 jstring encryptionKey,
                                                                 jstring inputFile,
                                                                 jstring outputFile);

JNIEXPORT jint  JNICALL
Java_com_example_nimashahbazi_mooshak_EncryptingActivity_encrypt(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj,
                                                                 jstring encryptionKey,
                                                                 jstring inputFile,
                                                                 jstring outputFile) {

    const char *_encryptionKey = env->GetStringUTFChars(encryptionKey, NULL);
    const char *_inputFile = env->GetStringUTFChars(inputFile, NULL);
    const char *_outputFile = env->GetStringUTFChars(outputFile, NULL);

    ByteArray key, enc;
    size_t file_len;

    FILE *input, *output;

    srand(time(0));

    size_t key_len = 0;
    while (_encryptionKey[key_len] != 0)
        key.push_back(_encryptionKey[key_len++]);

    input = fopen(_inputFile, "rb");
    if (input == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot read file '%s'\n", _inputFile);
        return 1;
    }

    output = fopen(_outputFile, "wb");
    if (output == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot write file '%s'\n", _outputFile);
        return 1;
    }

    Aes256 aes(key);

    fseek(input, 0, SEEK_END);
    file_len = ftell(input);
    fseek(input, 0, SEEK_SET);
    printf("File is %zd bytes\n", file_len);

    enc.clear();
    aes.encrypt_start(file_len, enc);
    fwrite(enc.data(), enc.size(), 1, output);

    while (!feof(input)) {
        unsigned char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
        size_t buffer_len;

        buffer_len = fread(buffer, 1, BUFFER_SIZE, input);
        printf("Read %zd bytes\n", buffer_len);
        if (buffer_len > 0) {
            enc.clear();
            aes.encrypt_continue(buffer, buffer_len, enc);
            fwrite(enc.data(), enc.size(), 1, output);
        }
    }

    enc.clear();
    aes.encrypt_end(enc);
    fwrite(enc.data(), enc.size(), 1, output);

    fclose(input);
    fclose(output);

    return 0;
}

JNIEXPORT jint  JNICALL
Java_com_example_nimashahbazi_mooshak_DecryptingActivity_decrypt(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj,
                                                                 jstring encryptionKey,
                                                                 jstring inputFile,
                                                                 jstring outputFile) {

    const char *_encryptionKey = env->GetStringUTFChars(encryptionKey, NULL);
    const char *_inputFile = env->GetStringUTFChars(inputFile, NULL);
    const char *_outputFile = env->GetStringUTFChars(outputFile, NULL);

    ByteArray key, dec;
    size_t file_len;

    FILE *input, *output;

    srand(time(0));

    size_t key_len = 0;
    while (_encryptionKey[key_len] != 0)
        key.push_back(_encryptionKey[key_len++]);

    input = fopen(_inputFile, "rb");
    if (input == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot read file '%s'\n", inputFile);
        return 1;
    }

    output = fopen(_outputFile, "wb");
    if (output == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot write file '%s'\n", outputFile);
        return 1;
    }

    Aes256 aes(key);

    fseek(input, 0, SEEK_END);
    file_len = ftell(input);
    fseek(input, 0, SEEK_SET);
    printf("File is %zd bytes\n", file_len);

    aes.decrypt_start(file_len);

    while (!feof(input)) {
        unsigned char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
        size_t buffer_len;

        buffer_len = fread(buffer, 1, BUFFER_SIZE, input);
        printf("Read %zd bytes\n", buffer_len);
        if (buffer_len > 0) {
            dec.clear();
            aes.decrypt_continue(buffer, buffer_len, dec);
            fwrite(dec.data(), dec.size(), 1, output);
        }
    }

    dec.clear();
    aes.decrypt_end(dec);
    fwrite(dec.data(), dec.size(), 1, output);

    fclose(input);
    fclose(output);

    return 0;
}
```

and this is my android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := native-lib
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := native-lib.cpp\
                   aes256.cpp

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := aes256.hpp

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

This is my CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

add_library(native-lib SHARED src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp)
add_library(aes256 SHARED src/main/cpp/aes256.cpp)

find_library(log-libd log )

target_link_libraries(native-lib ${log-lib})

target_link_libraries(aes256 ${log-lib})
```

And this is my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.nimashahbazi.mooshak"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags "-frtti -fexceptions"
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path 'CMakeLists.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.github.angads25:filepicker:1.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.daimajia.numberprogressbar:library:1.4@aar'
    compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.4.+'
    compile 'com.github.johnkil.android-appmsg:appmsg:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
    compile group: 'net.lingala.zip4j', name: 'zip4j', version: '1.2.4'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

There are also a couple of more files called aes256.cpp and aes256.hpp that are used from [here](https://github.com/Urban82/Aes256).

I have checked every proposed solution on the topic and they are mostly on the name and format of C++ function but I can't find the problem here. Can anybody please help me here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/45268742/192373 Your case looks similar

Comment: @AlexCohn Thank you very much, the problem was exactly the same...

Comment: Please note that your project does not use the **Android.mk** file, but rather **CMakeLists.txt**; thus, I am removing the irrelevant tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm writing this for further similar issues as the accepted answer as Alex has explained in the comments. I had to add "extern C" to the definition of functions in native-lib:

```
extern "C"
{
JNIEXPORT jint  JNICALL
Java_com_example_nimashahbazi_mooshak_EncryptingActivity_encrypt(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj,
                                                                 jstring encryptionKey,
                                                                 jstring inputFile,
                                                                 jstring outputFile);

JNIEXPORT jint  JNICALL
Java_com_example_nimashahbazi_mooshak_DecryptingActivity_decrypt(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj,
                                                                 jstring encryptionKey,
                                                                 jstring inputFile,
                                                                 jstring outputFile);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you are trying to load the wrong library - your Android.mk states your library name is `Mooshak` (via LOCAL_MODULE), yet you are using `System.loadLibrary("native-lib");`

You should use: `System.loadLibrary("Mooshak");` instead.

Comment: I have actually tried that. When I load "Mooshak" the catch phrase is executed and it says "WARNING: Could not load native library" and again the same error since it can not load the library. I also changed the LOCAL_MODULE to "native-lib" and still it says no implementation found for int com.example....

Comment: So you should see why it did not find the library - perhaps the jni folder is not set properly in the gradle. The mk file and loadlibrary must be synched and use the same name.

Comment: Sorry to bother this much, when I change LOCAL_MODULE to "native-lib" the library is loaded (since the catch phrase "WARNING:..." is not shown in logcat) but the main error is still there and says says "no implementation found for int com.example...". I have edited my post and changed LOCAL_MODULE to "native-lib" and also added build.gradle and CMakeLists.txt I was wondering maybe I'm doing wrong in them. could you please take a look?

Comment: No bother at all, I'll try to help as I can. What is the other library you are trying to load (System.loadLibrary("aes256")?

Comment: that is some code doing the encryption (AES256 encryption/decryption logic) and native-lib.cpp is just calling a few functions from it to encrypt and decrypt files with some key. In other words it's like aes256 is the library and native-lib is the use case. Trying to make things work, I even removed this aes256 from android.mk and CMakeLists.txt and EncryptingActivity.java but nothing changed and the same error is still there (since I am a newbie to NDK I think I was doing useless work loading and having aes256 in different places and just importing it in native-lib.cpp was enough).